# mAP calculation in object detection

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, average-precision

I'm quite confused as to how I can calculate the AP (average precision) or mAP (mean average precision) to evaluate an object detection model.

I specifically want to know if the True Positives (TP) from one image related to one class should be calculated after or before applying the **non-max suppression**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the true positives after non-maxima suppression.

Generally object detection algorithms are evaluated on the final predictions rather than intermediate results. Non-maxima suppression is an important part of many object detection algorithms (e.g. SSD), and has some parameters which need to be tuned. Also if you do calculate mAP before non-maxima suppression your results will probably be worse.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is correct? Is there a citation or other argument that can support your statement?

Comment: I'm sorry for the terse response but the original asker didn't ask for a explanation just what he should do. I thought a brief response would be clearest. As mentioned in the edited answer, I think there is a strong convention for apply performance measures to final outputs not intermediate results. I don't know of a citation that supports this off the top of my head.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the edit -- I think it makes the post stronger.

Comment: if you check this paper [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03476.pdf), it will elaborate on this answer, thanks